# Convert YYYY-MM-DD to Aug 26, 2022

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

I have date in the form of YYYY-MM-DD how can i format that date into Aug 26, 2022.

```
def return_date():
    date_returned = YYYY-MM-DD
```

return date_returned in form of Aug 26, 2022

Comment: reverse of it bro 2022-08-26 to Aug 26, 2022 title is clear

Answer (score 2):

here is your code:

```
from datetime import date

date_string = '2022-08-26'
date.fromisoformat(date_string).strftime('%b %d, %Y')  # 'Aug 26, 2022'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily understand with this example:

```
from datetime import datetime
   # Get current Date
   date = datetime.now()
   # Represent dates in short textual format
   print("dd-MMM-yyyy:", date.strftime("%b %d, %Y"))

   # prints "dd-MMM-yyyy: Aug 26, 2022"
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: OP wants to convert an existing date, not today's.

Answer (score 1):

Use strptime to decode the string then strftime to format it to your liking as follows:

```
from time import strptime, strftime


def return_date(ds): # data as string in the form YYYY-MM-DD
    return strftime('%b %d, %Y', strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d'))


print(return_date('2022-08-26'))
```

**Output:**

```
Aug 26, 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
import datetime

def return_date(ymd_format):
    year, month, day = ymd_format.split("-")
    return datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day)).strftime("%b %d, %Y")

print(return_date("2022-08-26")) # prints "Aug 26, 2022"
```

Comment: yes but the date argument is string with 2022-08-26 i tried with above logic but doesn't work your return is correct

Comment: You should not split the string but rather use `strptime` `datetime.datetime.strptime("2022-08-26", "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%b %d, %Y")`